# Can a Noun or Noun phrase ever be Secondary Predicate complement or adjunct?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, complements, predicate

**1**

She drank the coffee [hot] - **adjective**
The winter froze the Lake [solid]-**adjective**

Sam painted the wall [green] - **adjective**
The boy delivered the package [wet] - **adjective**

She sells them [new] - **adjective**

*All of the adjectives in the above sentences modify {Object} (even though some can be ambiguous)*

**2**

The soldiers arrived the camp [exhausted] - **adjective**

The cup arrived [broken] - **adjective**

The lake froze [solid] - **adjective**

I started this project [quite enthusiastic] - **adjective phrase**

*All of the adjectives in the above sentences modify {Subject}*

**My Question**

Can I use a Noun or Noun Phrase in the place of adjectives?

As in:-

**3**

She drank the coffee [the tastiest concoction] - **Noun phrase**

The winter froze the Lake [a solid block] - **Noun phrase**

Sam painted the wall [colour of the sky] - **Noun phrase**

The boy delivered the package [a torn bundle] - **Noun Phrase**

---

Can a noun or noun phrase act as modifier in the place of adjectives?

---

Sam named his son [John] - **Noun**

John here acts as a modifier and is inevitable- so it is a complement.

To me, I'm not a native speaker, some of the sentences in the top-most 2 sections sound they're Resultative constructions -- adjective comes as a result of some action.

And some others sound like Depictive constructions -- the adjective modifies a subject or object that are static and do not undergo a change or anything.

---

And to my exotic ears these constructions sound alright. Whether there is an adjective as the complement or noun as the complement they equally sound like a result of some action in one case, and in another a less hassle modification to the subject or object.

---

The sentences with [adjective] as complement are, according to a number of sources, true and they make sense to everyone.

But the problem here is not that.
The question here is whether the the Adjectives replaced by Nouns and Noun phrases make sense (3 and 4 section).

They do make sense to me, being a foreigner.

And finally- in linguistic terms what are they called? (1 and 2 sections)

Is there a strict line restricting the formation of such constructions? (as there can be an infinite number of Depictive and Resultative circumstances).

Comment: In your first 6 examples, the adjectives are not modifiers of the objects, but are depictive predicative adjuncts, i.e they are modifiers in the verb phrase. They are predicative, of course, because they refer to a predicand, i.e. the subject NPs.

Comment: Thank you. My doubt is whether such a construction is possible. I think those adjectives are complements or adjuncts of the sentence as you have described. Is it possible to replace them with nouns as I described below?

Comment: "Sam painted the wall the color of the sky" works fine (if you add the word **the**).  But your other examples don't.

Comment: There are a number of such constructions possible. They are governed by verbs and they are idiomatic for the most part: _She shot him dead. They buried her alive. They wanted him alive/dead. They discovered him alive. They hated him alive._ Etc. The constructions have quite different meanings, depending on the verb. It's pretty arbitrary, I'm afraid. See Georgia Green, "How Abstract Is Surface Structure?" in CLS 6.